# How to setup health check page in django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I have a webapp which required authentication to access any page of it. But for my ELB to work I have to setup health-check page for ELB so that ELB discover django app.

This page should return HTTP 200 and no auth required. How do I setup this with django/nginx world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOT RECOMMENDED - this was a quick and dirty way to get Django up and running with ELB, but in most cases a health check response should be returned directly from your application code. See the rest of the answers for a better solution.**

---

This is something better handled by nginx, so the fact that it's serving a django app should make no difference.

You will first need to configure ELB's health check to ping a specific URL of your instance, say `/elb-status`. You can follow the instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-healthchecks.html#update-health-check-config

After that, all you need to do is set up nginx to always send back an HTTP 200 status code. You can add something like this to your `server` block in `nginx.conf`:

```
location /elb-status {
    access_log off;
    return 200;
}
```

See this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/518220/nginx-solution-for-aws-amazon-elb-health-checks-return-200-without-if) for more details.

Comment: I am not sure it is a good idea - It indeed works but if you have application-level errors it might miss it.

Comment: Definitely not a good idea - especially in the container world where you can think everything is up and running healthy from ps but when you actually try to make requests you get 502s due to network setup.

Comment: Chiming in the the others. Just because nginx is working, doesn't mean the applications behind it are. Often if you're using ELB, you're not relying on nginx's health checks either and a location block would bypass those anyway.

Comment: Agreed, I wouldn't recommend this approach anymore. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 18):

Here is another solution using Django Middleware.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


class HealthCheckMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.path == '/health':
            return HttpResponse('ok')
        return self.get_response(request)
```

And put your `HealthCheckMiddleware` in front of other middlewares in `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'yourdjangoapp.middleware.HealthCheckMiddleware',
    ......
]
```

And your application will always respond to path `/health` with `ok` as long as your app is running regardless of any configurations and authentication.

Comment: It's more lightweight compared to installing a new python package. I like it more :)

Comment: this status check is good, if the client only needs to check if the service is reachable but it does not check if all required services are running. When used as the first middleware, this check also ignores database connection erros, which can be interesting in some cases.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, the file needs to be at `yourdjangoapp/middleware.py`

Answer (score 10):

You can use `django-health-check` 3rd party app.

Install it using pip -

```
pip install django-health-check
```

Configue URL as -

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    url(r'^health_check/', include('health_check.urls')),
]
```

and add the health_check applications to your INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'health_check',                             # required
]
```

More details : https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/django-health-check

Now you can confiure ELB health check url as -  `/health_check/`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue at one point and we ended up creating django-heartbeat:

https://github.com/pbs/django-heartbeat

It provides an endpoint for making sure your app is up and running.
Plus some other useful "checkers" that you can enable, out of the box, to surface information about like:

- build version
- python, django or other dependencies
- database(s), cache(s) information, etc

https://github.com/pbs/django-heartbeat#available-checkers

If you find it useful, feel free to ⭐ it.

If you need any additional functionalities or want to contribute - let us know or just go ahead and open a PR.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/elb-health-check')
def check_httpd_service():
    server = xmlrpclib.Server('http://'+supervisor_host+':'+supervisor_rpc_port+'/RPC2')

    state = server.supervisor.getProcessInfo(process)
    print state['statename']
    if state['statename'] == 'RUNNING':
        return state['statename'], 200
    else:
        return state['statename'], 500
```

Define the variables accordingly.

The above code is an example to create a custom api without authentication.  It can be invoked by HTTP GET request method and It can be used to perform health check from ELB.

It is just an example, you can use your own idea with flask/django to create a custom health check service for ELB.

Here I am control my application with supervisor, a process control system. From supervisor I can track the status of the application. Supervisor reloads the application, if it is exited.

http://supervisord.org/

If the service is running, the server will return 200 response code. If the service is not running on the host, it will return 500 response code. Based on this response code, we can route the traffic in the load balancer.