# How to pass AWS ELB health check with Django ALLOWED_HOSTS = [my-site.com]

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I have a Django application deployed on AWS via ECS (Dockerized) using gunicorn and nginx. As the
`DEBUG=False` 
for Django deployment I've configured a logging setting to receive logs on WARNINGs & above via `mail_admins`.

With a standard setup on nginx configuration (below) I started to receive tons of logs (mails) with  'BadRequest' or 'DisallowedHost' errors (most probably scanning/scraping bots) which were rejected by Django as I have set my `ALLOWED_HOSTS=[my-site.com]`.

nginx.conf

```
upstream django-backend {
    server 172.17.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django-backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I followed examples from following solutions to block the traffic hitting my Django application:

- [by @Brent O'Connor from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238506/djangos-suspiciousoperation-invalid-http-host-header/17477436#17477436)
- [by @Janusz Skonieczny from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220519/how-to-disable-djangos-invalid-http-host-error)
- [nginx docs here](https://https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names.com)

Having ultimately nginx.conf updated with:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name "";
    return      444;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-site.com;
    # Rest of configuration
}
```

This worked quite well, however, I couldn't setup the nginx in such way to allow AWS ELB to perform the Health check and I had following logs in AWS:

```
xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [26/Feb/2024:19:30:03 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 444 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [26/Feb/2024:19:30:03 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 444 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [26/Feb/2024:19:30:03 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 444 0 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
```

I have a Health Check set up from: [by @Watt Iamsuri here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920688/how-to-setup-health-check-page-in-django)

Anyone would have any suggestion on solution how to pass the AWS ELB Health check in this case?